# Send PHP query result via JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to send a Query result as JSON but when i use console.log it shows empty result.

**PHP Code:**

```
 function getCountries($countries){
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT DISTINCT id, type, level, code, name, durations FROM destinations where gateway_code="YBG" ORDER BY name' );
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
      {
         echo json_encode($row); // I have doubt here, i want to send complete Query result as JSON


      }
      exit();
  } 

  $abc = $_POST['countries'];
  getCountries($abc);
```

**Ajax** [Sending data works fine but response not working):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $leavingFrom = $('#select-leaving-from');
  $leavingFrom.on('change', function() {
  var $city_code = this.value;
  loadDepartures($city_code);
 });
});


function loadDepartures($cityname){
 var dataString = $cityname;
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQuery.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'get_data.php',
 datatype: 'json',
 data: {'countries': dataString},
 success: function (output, textStatus) {
                console.log(output);
        }
   });
 }); 
}
```

The only issue is that i am unable to send JSON data (Query Result) to Ajax back. Need suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting invalid JSON (well, valid JSON, multiple times, creating an invalid JSON string, if that makes sense).  You need to build the entire array, then JSON encode it:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
$json = [];
//Query here.
while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_array( //query ) )
{
    $tmp = array(
           'Prop1' => $result['Prop1Value'],
           'Prop2' => $result['Prop2Value'],
           'Prop3' => $result['Prop3Value'] );
    array_push( $json, $tmp );
}

$jsonString = json_encode( $json );
echo $jsonString;
```

Pretty generic layout that I use. Swap out the 'Props' for you DB columns and values. And then when you use

```
outputArray = JSON.parse( output );
```

You will get an array with values that can be referenced with parsed like so

```
myProp1 = outputArray[ 0 ].Prop1 ;
```

Hope this helps!!!!

EDIT: The Prop values that you reference with $result, coordinate with your DB Table columns, if you column was called 'Capitals' you would reference it with

```
'Capital' => $result['Capitals'],
```

and do your other columns in the same manner before and after.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a header problem, try updating your headers :

`header("Content-Type: application/json");`